# Computer boots directly to Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7, vaio

I bought VAIO E14A16.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 along-side Windows 7(dual boot) from CD., When I reboot, it starts Windows 7 directly.

If I press <kbd>F11</kbd> it says `no operating system found`

Where did I go wrong?

Is it VAIO which is affecting?

What can I do to fix this problem?

edit
as i said i installed 64 bit version via pen drive (outside windows) with booting from pendrive and than intalling it.

i have no idea what grub is, and there are so many partitions vaio made. i tried to change boot from UEFI to lagacy, but it was saying some boot loader problem. i don't wanna remove windows 7. so before things get wrong i switched back to UEFI.
what exactly i need to do to make ubuntu run?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you install the bootloader to mbr (did you install grub at all?)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify your hard drive when you got to partitioning?
Will your hard drive boot with the flash drive that you used for installation plugged in?
If so boot your hard drive, remove the flash drive and in terminal run: `update-grub`

Comment: i partitioned well, after that there was a screen saying remove your installing device which i did, but then it was starting windows directly...
i tried to change the UEFI to legacy in boot menu. but than none of them were working, for now i changed back to UEFI

Answer (score 0):

The message from Boot-repair-disk that helped me, especially the last sentence:

> ```
> If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
> If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
> For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi
> ```